# Purrr-fused about arranging date column

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to arrange a listcolumn using purrr. But just creating a toy example is making me utterly confused:

```
s <- tibble(b = as.integer(runif(
  n = 10, min = 0, max = 20
)))
s$e <-
  map(s$b,  ~ sample(seq(
    as.Date('1990/01/01'), as.Date('2010/01/01'), by = "day"
  ), size = .))
```

I thought I could do something like this:

```
s2 <- s %>% map('b') %>% 
  mutate(e = map(~ sample(seq(as.Date('1990/01/01'),
                              as.Date('2010/01/01'), by = "day"),
                          size = .)))
```

However, this does not work. What am I missing here?

Now, I'd like to arrange the dates in the listcolumn in ascending order and extract the first and last date. How would I do this in purrr-manner?
I've tried different variations on

```
s %>% map('e') %>% map_df(~arrange(.))
```

but clearly I'm missing something here...

My desired output is a new list-column in the dataframe `s` where the unarranged dates in the list-column `s$e` are arranged in ascending order in a new list-column `s$new_arranged_dates`.

```
> s
# A tibble: 10 × 3
       b           e       new_arranged_dates    
   <int>      <list>            <list>    
1     15 <date [15]>           <date [15]>
2      0  <date [0]>           <date [0]>
3      7  <date [7]>             etc
4      6  <date [6]>
5      3  <date [3]>
6     14 <date [14]>
7     15 <date [15]>
8     13 <date [13]>
9     13 <date [13]>
10    11 <date [11]>
```

EDIT 290817:

```
s2 <- s %>% 
  mutate(e = map(b,~ sample(seq(as.Date('1990/01/01'),
                              as.Date('2010/01/01'), by = "day"),
                          size = .))) %>% mutate(new_arranged_dates =map(e,~.[order(.)]))
```

Gets me what I want. However, I do not understand why

```
s2 <- s %>% 
  mutate(e = map(b,~ sample(seq(as.Date('1990/01/01'),
                              as.Date('2010/01/01'), by = "day"),
                          size = .))) %>% mutate(new_arranged_dates=map(e,~arrange(.)))
```

results in

```
Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: Not sure what `map('b')` and `map('e')` are doing. Just returns null for me.  And re first part, `e = map(...` is missing data. Try
`s %>% mutate(e = b %>% map(~ sample(seq(as.Date('1990/01/01'), as.Date('2010/01/01'), by = "day"), size = .)))`

Comment: Still not sure what you're looking for, provide us an example of your desired output (dont just say you want a new list)

Comment: @Simon Jackson ``e = map(...`` is not missing data, its in the pipe, doesnt need the call to data

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian - Doesn't the pipe just insert `s` as the first argument to `mutate()`? This doesn't seem to carry through to `map_df()` for me. E.g., if I run the above without `map('e')`, or more simply `s %>% mutate(e = map(~ .))`, I get following error: `Error: argument ".f" is missing, with no default`. To me, this indicates that it's treating the argument as the first argument - the data - and is missing the second argument - the function. Did you try run this?

Comment: @Simon Jackson when using commands such as ``mutate`` in dplyr's pipe you do not need (nor should you include) the dataframe as the first argument (or as any argument). ``.f`` error might be resulting from missing arguments in ``map()`` unrelated to lack of a data call

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian, yes, `.f` error is telling us that the **function argument** is missing. I suspect that it's because map() takes data as a first argument and a function as it's second. Thus, if the data is **not** being piped in, then `e = map(~ .)` is treating `~.` as the first argument (data), and there is no second argument (function). This explains the error. To illustrate, `s %>% mutate(e = map(~ .))` returns that error, whereas `s %>% mutate(e = map(b, ~ .))` works fine. The second working example provides the two required arguments, with the data being the `b` column of `s`.

Comment: @Simon Jackson I think I miss understood what you were saying earlier, I thought you were referring to the original data frame ``s`` and not the vector  ``b`` (you wrote "data" I read it as "dataframe") my bad. I stand corrected yes, you're right.

Comment: @Misha It's still not clear to me what you want. You need to actually provide us with an exact example of your desired output. The dates are a list of lists. How can we order them if each row of the list has multiple dates?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122056/discussion-between-simon-jackson-and-cyrus-mohammadian).

Comment: If s$e[5] gives 1990/01/01, 2010/01/01 and 2000/01/01 then the resulting tibble s$new_arranged_dates[5] should give 1990/01/01, 2000/01/01 and 2010/01/01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now an old question, but what you need here is just `sort`:

```
s <- s %>% mutate(new_arranged_dates = map(e, sort))

str(s)

## Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ b                 : int  5 16 3 14 16 5 14 1 1 5
##  $ e                 :List of 10
##   ..$ : Date, format: "1991-09-28" "2006-09-12" "1993-03-04" ...
##   ..$ : Date, format: "2000-04-30" "2002-05-16" "1991-10-01" ...
##   ..$ : Date, format: "1998-04-20" "2006-12-16" "2000-10-15"
##   ..$ : Date, format: "2000-02-14" "1993-01-20" "1998-03-26" ...
##   ..$ : Date, format: "1992-07-06" "1995-08-18" "2005-01-24" ...
##   ..$ : Date, format: "1996-05-01" "1993-03-01" "2001-10-11" ...
##   ..$ : Date, format: "2006-04-24" "2008-03-26" "2007-12-08" ...
##   ..$ : Date, format: "2007-04-15"
##   ..$ : Date, format: "1998-07-16"
##   ..$ : Date, format: "2004-04-25" "1994-12-01" "1998-12-21" ...
##  $ new_arranged_dates:List of 10
##   ..$ : Date, format: "1991-09-28" "1993-03-04" "2005-02-15" ...
##   ..$ : Date, format: "1990-08-19" "1991-10-01" "1992-12-15" ...
##   ..$ : Date, format: "1998-04-20" "2000-10-15" "2006-12-16"
##   ..$ : Date, format: "1990-01-21" "1990-12-29" "1992-06-09" ...
##   ..$ : Date, format: "1992-02-12" "1992-07-06" "1993-04-30" ...
##   ..$ : Date, format: "1991-07-30" "1993-03-01" "1996-05-01" ...
##   ..$ : Date, format: "1990-12-05" "1993-08-23" "1994-12-09" ...
##   ..$ : Date, format: "2007-04-15"
##   ..$ : Date, format: "1998-07-16"
##   ..$ : Date, format: "1994-12-01" "1998-12-21" "2004-04-25" ...
##  - attr(*, "vars")= chr
```

To extract the earliest and latest date, `map` `min` and `max`:

```
s %>% mutate(earliest = map(e, min), 
             latest = map(e, max)) %>% 
    unnest(earliest, latest, .drop = FALSE)

## # A tibble: 10 × 5
##        b           e new_arranged_dates   earliest     latest
##    <int>      <list>             <list>     <date>     <date>
## 1      5  <date [5]>         <date [5]> 1991-09-28 2007-07-19
## 2     16 <date [16]>        <date [16]> 1990-08-19 2007-10-08
## 3      3  <date [3]>         <date [3]> 1998-04-20 2006-12-16
## 4     14 <date [14]>        <date [14]> 1990-01-21 2006-06-11
## 5     16 <date [16]>        <date [16]> 1992-02-12 2008-12-18
## 6      5  <date [5]>         <date [5]> 1991-07-30 2007-10-23
## 7     14 <date [14]>        <date [14]> 1990-12-05 2009-04-11
## 8      1  <date [1]>         <date [1]> 2007-04-15 2007-04-15
## 9      1  <date [1]>         <date [1]> 1998-07-16 1998-07-16
## 10     5  <date [5]>         <date [5]> 1994-12-01 2008-01-10
```

There's no `map_date` format that will automatically simplify to date, so you'll have to use `unnest` to simplify. `.drop = FALSE` specifies to keep the other list columns.

Answer (score 0):

So- the basic error here is that arrange prefers a dataframe and will not order a vector. Coercing the looped list to a data_frame solved the problem, but it took me awhile to figure out that the name of the resulting coerced data_frame column also is .

So this works:

```
  library(dplyr)
  s <- tibble(b = as.integer(runif(
       n = 10, min = 0, max = 20
       )))
  s <-
  s %>% mutate(e = map(b,  ~ sample(seq(
    as.Date('1990/01/01'), as.Date('2010/01/01'), by = "day"
  ), size = .)))

  s <- s2 %>% mutate(arranged = map(e,  ~ arrange(data_frame(.), .)))
```

Hint: creating a new function with a browser() statement that is called from map helped a lot and will probably be helpful for other people as well.